# open multiple tabs within one webview

Tags: android, webview

I want to open multiple tabs within one **webview**. I can manage to load one url at a time. I am understanding that i have to customized my **webview**  to do so. Is it possible, like as my below picture ?

Any suggestion , tutorial or guideline is appreciated. 
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tabs are simply not part of WebView, you need to develop such features around it yourself.

E.g. you could use a [TabLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.html) to implement the tabs, and update the state of the WebView according to the selected tab. You can easily find tutorials all over the place detailing tabs.